# Sending Email notification using trigger

Tags: trigger

I have created two objects Flight and Flight Attendant with fields name,gender,email Having lookup between them..whenever I insert Flight Attendant via Flight Object then email alert should be sent to that particular Flight Attendant..how do i achieve this?
I'm a beginner in salesforce..please help

Comment: You should invest some time working through these [Developer Workbooks](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Forcedotcomworkbook). The "Apex Workbook" includes material about triggers and there is a [Messaging.sendEmail](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm#apex_System_Messaging_sendEmail) method available in Apex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please look at the sample code:

```
trigger SendEmailToAccount on Contact (after insert) {
    if(Trigger.isAfter){
        if(Trigger.isInsert ){ 
            //helper class for single email but bulk messages
            HelperContactTrigger.sendEmail(trigger.new);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public with sharing class HelperContactTrigger {
    //static method
    public static List<Contact> sendEmail(List<Contact> contacts) {

        //query on template object
        EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where name=:'Sales: New Customer Email'];

        //list of emails
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

        //loop
        for(Contact con : contacts){

            //check for Account
            if(con.AccountId == null && con.Email != null){

                //initiallize messaging method
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage singleMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                //set object Id
                singleMail.setTargetObjectId(con.Id);

                //set template Id
                singleMail.setTemplateId(et.Id);

                //flag to false to stop inserting activity history
                singleMail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

                //add mail
                emails.add(singleMail);

               //This will not send email to contact  
               emails.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);
            }
        }

        //send mail
        Messaging.sendEmail(emails);

        return contacts;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this was different when you wrote your answer, but as of right now `setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient` is a method on `SingleEmailMessage`, not the List. So inside the `if` statement, the last two LOC should trade places, and `emails.setTreatTarget...` should be changed to `singleMail.setTreatTarget...`