# Send email on trigger

Tags: trigger, email, email-template

How can I send email through trigger?
And email Ids should be hardcoded lets say "test1@test.test" & "test2@test.test". 
And condition for trigger is, if Logged in user's country is INDIA.

Comment: Refer to this link:

http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38947/sending-email-notification-using-trigger

Comment: why are you going with Trigger? it can be done from workflow just email , is it same object or different objects?

Comment: How the trigger is firing. Is it initiated from any vf page/standard page?

Comment: from standard page only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is very broad. Noone will be writing end to end trigger for you. Folks the community are always looking to help people who try out a code and are stuck in between. For your reference, here is one example of trigger - [Sending Email notification using trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38947/sending-email-notification-using-trigger)

I would suggest, figuring out a field on User that would identify the country of logged in User. If you already have the field identified, you can query User record and use that field as a condition.

Few more good read for you.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_sendemail.htm This link will help you understand the attributes of sending email.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm This link will help you get the logged in users information.