# Writing an APEX trigger & test class that sends an email?

Tags: apex

I'm really new to APEX and I'm trying to write a trigger that emails the owner of an account when the note is added. I think I have the logic correct, but I'm not sure how to translate that into the code. This is a combination of my own code and the code I have found online, so here's what I have so far:

```
    trigger FireNoteEmailTrigger on Note (after insert) {
    //grab ID of the note
    Note note = trigger.new[0];
    //find account that has that note ID
    Account foundAccount = note.Parent;
    String emailTitle = note.Title;
    //find owner ID of that account id
    User foundOwner = foundAccount.Owner;
    //find email of that owner ID
    String ownerEmail = foundOwner.Email;
    //send email notification to ownerEmail using emailTitle as title
    EmailMessage e = new EmailMessage();
    e.Status = '5'; 
    e.TextBody = emailTitle;
    e.Subject = emailTitle;
    e.ToAddress = ownerEmail;
    insert e;
    List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> 
        results = Messaging.sendEmailMessage(new ID[] { e.id });
    System.assertEquals(1, results.size());
    System.assertEquals(true, results[0].success);
}
```

This seems to save without errors. Here's my test class however, which I have no idea what to write for:

```
@isTest
private class FireNoteEmailTriggerTestClass {
    static testMethod void validateFireNoteEmailTrigger() {
        Note n = new Note();
        insert n;

        Test.startTest();

        Account a = new Account();
        insert a;
        User u = new User();

        insert u;

        Test.stopTest();

        System.assertEquals(u.Id, n.Id);
    }
}
```

The above of course doesn't work. Where do I go from here? Thanks!

Comment: There is already a question with an answer here. Please have a look at the answer.  [Send email from trigger](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/38947/4517)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to refer to a String variable as an SObject:

```
//You create it as a String here
String foundAccount = note.ParentId;
...
//You refer to it as an SObject here
String foundOwner = foundAccount.OwnerId;
```

You likely need to be querying your Account object somewhere and bringing back the values for that.

You have many other issues with this trigger besides that.  It needs bulkified and there are a few other related objects you need to pull as well.

Comment: Changed that, please see new code.