# notification when tagged myself in chatter feed salesforce

Tags: chatter

How do i get notified when i tag myself in chatter feed?

I am tagging myself through apex and not receiving a notification.

Can you help me in achieving this?

```
List<ConnectApi.BatchInput> batchInputs = new List<ConnectApi.BatchInput>();

for(sObject c : [select Name from user where name LIKE '%anurag%']){

     ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
     ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();
     ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
     ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();

     messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();
     //Mention user here
     mentionSegmentInput.id = userinfo.getUserId();
     messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(mentionSegmentInput);

     textSegmentInput.text = '\n'+' Chatter text here';
     messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);

     feedItemInput.body = messageBodyInput;
     feedItemInput.feedElementType = ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem;
     feedItemInput.subjectId = c.Id;

     ConnectApi.BatchInput batchInput = new ConnectApi.BatchInput(feedItemInput);
     batchInputs.add(batchInput);

 }

 ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElementBatch(Network.getNetworkId(), batchinputs);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can At Mention yourself in a post, it will not cause any of the notifications to kick off. So No Emails and No Lightning Notification.

What result are you trying to

Comment: Paul, i need to get notification when my child records have a picklist value of 'new'. So what I planned to do is to insert feeditems from trigger for child records that meet criteria. So when i create feeditems i need to get tagged to receive the notifications.

Comment: You could use a different Chatter Account to create the feed item, so when you get Mentioned, you will be notified.  
You can have the trigger send you an email.

Comment: Paul can please elaborate on how can i use other chatter account?

Comment: While doing my research i found that, you can't use @mention from other user. If this is true, how can I use other chatter account..am confused

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. You cannot impersonate a different user in a trigger.

You can always have the trigger send you an email.
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38947/sending-email-notification-using-trigger