# how to send an automatic email when lead status is converted to "Qualified" via apex and triggers

Tags: apex, trigger

I want to  send an automatic email when lead status is converted to "Qualified" , i tried it in workflow and process, it worked fine, now i want to try it in apex , i have ready made email template named "XXX" which shows as

Hello {!Lead.LastName}

Thank you for the registering with us 
Soon we will get back to you

Team EduProserra

my apex class is

```
public class emailSending {

    public String Lead { get; set; }
    public string toMail { get; set;}
    public string ccMail { get; set;}
    public string repMail { get; set;}

    public void sendMail(){
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        string[] to = new string[] {toMail};
        string[] cc = new string[] {ccMail};

        email.setToAddresses(to);
        if(ccMail!=null && ccMail != '')
            email.setCcAddresses(cc);
        if(repmail!=null && repmail!= '')
            email.setInReplyTo(repMail);

        email.setSubject('Thank you for the Registration');

        email.setHtmlBody('Hello, {!Lead.LastName} <br/><br/>Thank you for Registration. <br/>We will get back to you for more details<br/><br/>Regards<br/> EduPro Team');
        try{
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { email });
        }catch(exception e){
            apexpages.addmessage(new apexpages.message(apexpages.severity.error,e.getMessage()));
        }

        toMail = '';
        ccMail = '';
        repMail = '';
    }
}
```

how do i design a trigger for this??

Comment: I think you are lacking basic understanding about SF's triggers. Maybe try this module on trailhead: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers Or you could search SO, there are a lot of questions related to your matter: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38947/sending-email-notification-using-trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the trigger example. The best practice is to move email sending logic to separate triggerHandler apex class. However, if for test and clear understanding I have left it in the trigger.

So all you need to do is create a trigger on Lead object on insert and update. Check if new status is the one you need and it has changed and prepare massages storing them into list, which you should send in the end of the trigger execution.

```
trigger test on Lead (after insert, after update) {
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    List<Lead> leadsToSend = new List<Lead>();

    for (Lead lead_i : Trigger.NEW) {
        if (lead_i.Status == 'Qualified') {

            if (Trigger.oldMap != null) {
                Lead oldLead_i = Trigger.oldMap.get(lead_i.Id);

                if (lead_i.Status != oldLead_i.Status) {
                    leadsToSend.add(lead_i);
                }
            } else {
                leadsToSend.add(lead_i);
            }
        }
    }

    for (Lead lead_i : leadsToSend) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        /* form your email message here */
        emails.add(email);
    }

    Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>{emails});
}
```

Comment: Hi Mariia, why wouldn't you just use "for (Lead lead_i : Trigger.new)"? You would save one line and the code would be much easier to read for a beginner. OP clearly just gets started on triggers and will be using your approach for now. Also, I'd add a comment above "if (Trigger.oldMap != null)", which tells this question's audience that Trigger.oldMap is null in the context of an insert, but is always not null in the context of an update.

Comment: @Johannes Reasonable comment, editted the answer. I just used to work with maps.

Comment: Understandable, but also a bit complex for beginners. (Just remembering my beginner-days in SF.) Btw: It is just "Trigger.new", without the braces :)

Comment: Thank you so much Mariia

Comment: @  Johannes thank you for sharing the trialhead module on triggers, i will complete those and start experimenting on the actual triggers